# Embedding JNI dll into java

Tags: java, java-me, java-native-interface

Is it possible to embed JNI dll/so into java executable so we don't need to ship it externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no monolithic "Java executable" -- `java.exe` needs a directory tree full of support stuff. You can install your DLL in the "standard extensions" directory inside that tree, though -- native libraries for standard extensions go in `${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext/i386` (for example) on Linux and Mac, or ${JAVA_HOME}/bin on Windows -- so that the user doesn't install anything extra.

Comment: Since jar can be made as an executable, is it not possible to get this packaged along with it?

Comment: An "executable JAR" is just a JAR full of class files that, when you double-click on it, is launched by the JVM. You still need the separate JVM install. You actually *can* package a DLL inside a JAR if you want. If you do this, you have to include Java code that unpacks the DLL into a temporary directory and loads it from there. The JVM can't load the DLL directly from inside the JAR file.